# django rest powered by json using nosql

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to develop an REST app which is flexible in term's of fields, means new fields can be added or removed dynamically, fields can be powered using json.

for example,

Here is json, can be edited at runtime to add new field or remove existing field,

```
{
  "model": "MyModel",
  fields:{
    "title": "CharField",
    "description": "CharField"
  }
}
```

Serializer can be,

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta = MyModel
```

How to achieve this ? Any guidance/ suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add fields during runtime.

If you're using postgres you can use a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) instead.

**or**, but I'm not sure if this is a very good solution, you could do:

```
class MyModelField(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    fields = models.ManyToManyField(MyModelField)
```

the data would look like (which is maybe not what you're looking for):

```
{
    "fields":[
         {"key": "title", "value": "Some Title"},
         {"key": "description", "value": "Some Desc"}
    ]
}
```